# Function php variable unknown

Tags: php

```
function scale($src) {
    $max = 350;
    if (!isset($max, $src))
        return;
    $src = str_replace(" ", "%20", $src[1]);
    $info = @getimagesize($src);
    $sw = $info[0];
    $sh = $info[1];
    $addclass = false;
    $max_em = 0.06 * $max;
    if ($max < max($sw, $sh)) {
        if ($sw > $sh)
            $new = array($max_em . "em", "auto");
        if ($sw < $sh)
            $new = array("auto", $max_em . "em");
        $addclass = true;
    } else
        $new = array("auto", "auto");
    $id = mt_rand(0000, 9999);
    if ($new[0] == "auto" && $new[1] == "auto")
        $img = "<img src=\"" . $src . "\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" />";
    else
        $img = "<img id=\"r" . $id . "\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"" . $src . "\" " . ($addclass ? "class=\"resized\"" : "") . " style=\"width:" . $new[0] . ";height:" . $new[1] . ";\" />";
    return $img;
}
```

I have this function to resize images. It does the job when images are bigger, but when they are 600x600 for example, i get
Notice: Undefined variable: new in line

```
if ($new[0] == "auto" && $new[1] == "auto")
```

and

```
$img = "<img id=\"r" . $id . "\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"" . $src . "\" " . ($addclass ? "class=\"resized\"" : "") . " style=\"width:" . $new[0] . ";height:" . $new[1] . ";\" />";
```

For this case, else, $new should be `$new = array("auto", "auto");` , but it's not recognized.

Comment: This code is a mess. Put brackets everywhere. Use indentation. Probably you'll see the problem by yourself.

Comment: You don't have anything for `$sw == $sh`. Change `if ($sw > $sh) $new = array($max_em . "em", "auto"); if ($sw < $sh) $new = array("auto", $max_em . "em");` to `if ($sw > $sh) $new = array($max_em . "em", "auto"); else $new = array("auto", $max_em . "em");`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at following part, it becomes pretty clear:

```
if ($max < max($sw, $sh)) {
        if ($sw > $sh)
            $new = array($max_em . "em", "auto");
        if ($sw < $sh)
            $new = array("auto", $max_em . "em");
        $addclass = true;
    } else
        $new = array("auto", "auto");
```

translate it to values and you will see ..

```
if ($max < max($sw, $sh)) {
        if (600 > 600)
            $new = array($max_em . "em", "auto");
        if (600 < 600)
            $new = array("auto", $max_em . "em");
        $addclass = true;
        // None of the above ifs meet the case of 600x600 !!!!!
        // ----------------------------------------------------
    } else
        $new = array("auto", "auto");
```

Comment: You will have to either put an else case in there, or change one comparison to include the case when width and height is equal. Eg: if ($sw <= $sh) .. which would be the same as exchanging it with else...

Answer (score 0):

$new is never being initialized. You need to add new at the top of your code. All your if statements never meet true and $new is never assigned a variable. NOTE: Make sure you initialized your variables before using them.

```
function scale($src) {
    $max = 350;
    if (!isset($max, $src))
        return;
    $src = str_replace(" ", "%20", $src[1]);
    $info = @getimagesize($src);
    $sw = $info[0];
    $sh = $info[1];
    $addclass = false;
    $max_em = 0.06 * $max;
    $new = array('auto', 'auto'); //Initialized variable per (Catalin Deaconescu)

    if ($max < max($sw, $sh)) {
        if ($sw > $sh)
            $new = array($max_em . "em", "auto");
        if ($sw < $sh)
            $new = array("auto", $max_em . "em");
        $addclass = true;
    } else {
        $new = array("auto", "auto");
        $id = mt_rand(0000, 9999);
    }

    if ($new[0] == "auto" && $new[1] == "auto")
        $img = "<img src=\"" . $src . "\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" />";
    else
        $img = "<img id=\"r" . $id . "\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"" . $src . "\" " . ($addclass ? "class=\"resized\"" : "") . " style=\"width:" . $new[0] . ";height:" . $new[1] . ";\" />";
    return $img;

}
```

Comment: you should initialize `$new` to `array('auto', 'auto')`, so at least he can display the image if it gets to the `$sw == $sh` case

Answer (score 0):

here the probleme :

```
if ($sw > $sh)
    $new = array($max_em . "em", "auto");
    if ($sw < $sh)
    $new = array("auto", $max_em . "em");
```

you didn't match when $sw == $sh